# Multiple login forms

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My web applications is secured with Spring-security and now I'm trying to setup two different login pages. Here is my configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/mobile/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ONE','ROLE_TWO')" requires-channel="http"/>

    <form-login login-page="/loginm" login-processing-url="/loginm_check" default-target-url="/mobile/menu" authentication-failure-url="/loginmfailed"  />
    <logout logout-url="/logoutm" logout-success-url="/loginm" />
</http>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/main.html" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="http" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login_check" default-target-url="/main.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

The second form works well. But the first form doesn't seem to work at all. The server returns 404 for the login-processing-url="/loginm_check".

I'm using the latest Spring-Security 3.1.4.RELEASE.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make any sense if both use the same authentication. If you wan't a different page layout for mobile devices you should be solving it with view resolvers.

Comment: Your login for mobile should be under the /mobile URL. Currently it matches the default http element which doesn't recognize the URL. Next to that why should you have different configurations? As @bart already mentioned you can have a Spring `ViewResolver` handle that for you.

Comment: Well I thought that's the idea of Spring Security - to handle things instead of me writing from scratch. I already made it with view resolvers but for me the cleaner way to do is to use Spring's configuration. Anyway thanks for the hint with the URL, I' try that.

Comment: I tried changing login-processing-url to "/mobile/loginm_check" and I still get this 404 error

Comment: EDIT: changing the URL actually worked. Thanks!