# Multiple login using spring security, java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have multiple logins for my applications. I have defined security filters in two different configurations.

This one has `@Order(1)` for admin:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("userpassword")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login")
                .permitAll().and()
                .csrf();
    }
```

And other one:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/tasker/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/tasker/login")
                .usernameParameter("taskeremail").passwordParameter("taskerpassword")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll().and()
                .csrf();
    }
```

The first one for admin works fine but the second one is not even securing the `/tasker/**` urls.

Found simular questions but not answerd. Even I could not find anything helpful on spring reference. Please help.

Comment: I once asked this question (although with XML configuration) on a course in Udemy, when I was learning the Spring Framework. The tutor said multiple custom login forms were not possible using **spring security**, but now that I come across such questions, I guess that guy was wrong, or is it?

Comment: I must be possible using spring-security.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22947952/3640307) answer and let me know if this works. I too want to find an answer to this problem, but let's first make sure we've tried all the solutions before up-voting it for further attention which may result in a duplication vote or a close vote unless we are quite sure we do not have a solution.

Comment: using this it can be achieved but again I think I can use only one table in db for all type of users and grant them access according to the role. Not very promising though.