# How to configure two formLogin in Spring Security with Java based security config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am developing a web application with Spring Security. My application uses Java config completely, it doesn't have any XML.

My application has two login pages, one for front user login, another for back admin user login.
I have configured front user login:

```java
http
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/front/login")
        .permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
        .failureUrl("/front/login?error=1")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/front/logining")
        .usernameParameter("mobile")    
        .passwordParameter("password");
```

How can I configure back admin user login?
I have tried to add another `fromLogin`, but it's not working, the second `fromLogin` covers the first `formLogin`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! And please take a look to the site guide: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the accepted answer?
[Spring Security 3.2.1 Multiple login forms with distinct WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845474/spring-security-3-2-1-multiple-login-forms-with-distinct-websecurityconfigurerad)

Another aproach:

Different user login can be handled by the same formLogin by checking the Role

Basically you login once and you enable specific paths for specific roles.
`"http.authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/privateAdminActions/**").hasRole("ADMIN")"`